# Which service monitors the events like (reset,halt,power off) and in turn executes runlevel 6,0 or 3

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, linux-kernel, runlevel

When I issue power off to a device, ideally the kernel should get this event and then runlevel 0 should get executed.

As of now the hardware turns off but the runlevel 0 is not executed.

When i manually executed the script

> /etc/rc.d/rc

and hardcoded the runlevel value to 0 the script works fine and the system is halted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the changing of the run-level is done by the kernel modules the issue in my case was the binary that was responsible for issuing this reset was not packaged as it was missing in our package mapping list

Answer (score 1):

All the services of halt,reboot are present in /etc/init.d directory

your runlevel specific services are present in /etc/rc.d/ directory

rc.d directory convention was quite old

Comment: Hi Sundeep,
I am more concerned about the event which makes this runlevel 0 to be executed when a power off signal is received.